# Regarding UIView

Tags: iphone

is that necessary to set the property of uiview object

if not why?

```
IBOutlet UIView *feedback_View;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIView *feedback_View;
```

please give me the answer i m new in iphone thnx in advance..

Comment: IBOutlet is required only when you want to refer or say you want to access to your view in viewcontroller. There must be some way to tell view controller that your feedback_view is the view in your xib otherwise it is not required.Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it, it has to be set.  There are different ways of setting it, though, either code or graphically in the UI editor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question but here goes. It's not necessary to set the property of any object. When you set the property (and synthesize) you basically tell the compiler to automatically create setters and getters for the instance variable.  So you can do something like `[object.feedback_View someInstanceMethod]` without having to write a get method in the class.

If you want to reference the view from your nib with the UIView in your class, the only way I have seen that done is with an `IBOutlet`. If you're new to IOS developing remember to read the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/). Happy coding! cheers!